# C# Creation of n-number lists

Tags: c#, list

I would like to create multiple lists, filled according to conditions and evaluated.

```
// Inputs:
private int Number = 5;     //5, ...n
private int Que;

// Values to process:
private double Value;

private List<double> nList”1” = new List<double>();
private List<double> nList”2” = new List<double>();
….
private List<double> nList“Number” = new List<double>();

if(Que = 1) {nList”1”.Add(ValueX);}
if(Que = 2) {nList”2”.Add(ValueY);}
….

var Count1 = nList”1”.Count / .Average() / .Max() ….;
var Count2 = nList”2”. Count / .Average() / .Max() ….;
….
```

Comment: Hint : you can create a list of lists

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for 2D lists? You can create 2D lists by writing the following code:

```cs
List<List<double>> two_dimensional_array = new List<List<double>>();
```

You can add lists to it by doing:

```cs
List<double> example = new List<double> {3.14159, 2.71828}
two_dimensional_array.push(example);
```